# Modify Url in cakephp and add parameter on url?

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I remove the action name from the Url in cakephp?
I tried to do it from routes.php but not getting succed
my url is: http://www.example.com/liberty_new/users/home

In routes.php I have done

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'));
```

I would like to remove action name from the url and like to set only the parameter in url. 
if I use
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'home','parm1',param2));

in this redirection Url will look like

http://www.example.com/users/home/param1/param2
but I want url look like

http://www.example.com/users/param1/param2

where "users" is my controller name
please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'));
Router::connect('/users/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'));
```

Comment: Excellent! If this answer is the correct one, please set this answer as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'));
```

You should go to

```
/
```

What is not working?